# ¿Cómo evitar que se cierre mi modal al dar click a un botón que llama a una función?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Buenos tardes mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un botón "agregar" dentro de un modal que al dar click me adiciona una fila con un `<select>` y un `<input>`.

Lo que quiero es que al hacer *click* al botón agregar no se me recargue la pagina y se cierre el modal ya que eso genera que no se vea los componentes adicionados.

Este es el json de prueba.

Este es mi json cargarTipoDepreciacion.json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "1",
            "descripcion_breve": "AMORTIZACION DE SOFTWARE",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "2",
            "descripcion_breve": "DA DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO \r\n",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "3",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "4",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE EQUIPOS DIVERSOS",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "5",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE INFRAESTRUCTURA",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "6",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE MUEB.Y ENSERES",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "7",
            "descripcion_breve": "DA DEPRECIACION ASIGNADA",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Mi html y javascript

El botón agregar llama a una función que crea una fila un `<select>` y un `<input>` con datos de un  archivo json en ajax y cada vez que de *click* en el botón se creará una fila con un `<select>` y un `<input>` pero se recarga la pagina y no los llega a mostrar.

```
<section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnNuevo" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#exampleModal">Nuevo</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <div class="">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-sc" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Registro</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                <label for="inputEmail4">Proyecto a Cargar</label>
                                <input type="text" id="tempIdDepreciacion" hidden />
                                <input type="number" id="idCargar" hidden>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcionCarga" placeholder="Cargar">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                                        id="exampleCheck1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Transferir a</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-5" id="trans">
                                <label for="inputPassword4">Torre</label>
                                <input type="hidden" id="idTransferir">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcionTransferir"
                                    placeholder="Transferir">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="idDescripcion">Descripcion</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="idDescripcion" rows="3"></textarea>
                                <span id="referencia"></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="idCostoBienes">Ingresos</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idIngresos" placeholder="Ingresos">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="idCostoBienes">Costo Bienes</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idCostoBienes" placeholder="Costo Bienes">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="idManoObra">Mano Obra</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idManoObra" placeholder="Mano Obra">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="idGastoGen">Gastos Generales</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idGastoGen" placeholder="Gasto Generales">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label for="tipoDepreciacion">Depreciacion</label>
                        <div id="items">

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                                <!--<button id="finish" class="btn btn-primary">Listo</button>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--<div id="result"></div>-->



                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnActualizar">Actualizar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         var seleccionados=[];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            MantProyecto.init_botones();
        });

        var MantProyecto = function () {
            return {
                init_botones: function () {
                    $("#btnNuevo").click(function () {
                        MantProyecto.limpiar_controles();
                        $("#btnGuardar").show();
                        $("#btnActualizar").hide();

                    });
                    $("#add").click(function () {
                        if (seleccionados.length < 7) {
                            var valor = $('select:enabled').val();
                            valor != null ? seleccionados.push(valor) : null
                            $('.idDepreciacion').prop('disabled', true);
                            MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
                        }
                        if (seleccionados.length == 6)
                            $("#add").prop('disabled', true);
                        //MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
                    });
                },
                limpiar_controles: function () {

                    $("#idCargar").val("");
                    $("#descripcionCarga").val("");
                    $("#idTransferir").val("");
                    $("#descripcionTransferir").val("");
                    $("#idDescripcion").val("");
                    $("#idIngresos").val("");
                    $("#idCostoBienes").val("");
                    $("#idManoObra").val("");
                    $("#idGastoGen").val("");
                },
                cargaCombo: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'cargarTipoDepreciacion.json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (json) {
                            var items = document.getElementById("items");
                            //items.innerHTML += "";
                            var select = `
                            <div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                                <select class="idDepreciacion">
                            `;
                            for (let valor of json.data) {
                                if (!seleccionados.includes(valor.id_sub_catalogo)) 
                                select += "<option value='" + valor.id_sub_catalogo + "' >" + valor.descripcion_breve + "</option>";
                            }
                            var html = select + `</select> &nbsp;
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-2 valor" type="number" required/>  &nbsp;     
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>
                                        </div>`;
                            $("#items").append(html);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }();
    </script>
```

Comment: Lo mandas por el formulario?

Comment: Ponle al botón agregar, `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer uso del preventDefault() en la función:

```
$("#add").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (seleccionados.length < 7) {
    var valor = $('select:enabled').val();
    valor != null ? seleccionados.push(valor) : null
    $('.idDepreciacion').prop('disabled', true);
        MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
    }
    if (seleccionados.length == 6) {
       $("#add").prop('disabled', true);
       //MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
    }
});
```

Espero que te sirva :)